# Changing to Tail Recursive SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, tail-recursion

Ok, so I'm trying to change this function into Tail Recursive.  The Definition I have of Tail Recursive is to use a "Local Helper Function" to accumulate my answer and return it without calling the primary function recursively.

these functions work properly.

```
fun same_string(s1 : string, s2 : string) =
s1 = s2

fun all_except_option (name, []) = NONE
  | all_except_option (name, x::xs)=
case same_string (x , name) of
true  => SOME xs
  | false => case all_except_option(name,xs) of
         NONE   => NONE
           | SOME z => SOME(x::z)

fun get_substitutions1 ([],name2)    = [] (*get_substitutions2 is same but tail recursive *)
  | get_substitutions1 (x::xs,name2) = 
    case all_except_option (name2,x) of
        NONE   => get_substitutions1 (xs,name2)
      | SOME z  => z @ get_substitutions1(xs,name2)
```

So here are my attempts at tail recursion which do not work and I think I am missing something fairly basic that I am overlooking due to my lack of experience in SML.

```
fun get_substitutions2 (lst,name3) = 
let fun aux (xs,acc) =
 case all_except_option(name3,x::xs) of
     NONE   => aux(xs, acc)
   | SOME z => aux(xs, z::acc)
in
aux(lst,[])
end
```

and

```
fun get_substitutions2 (lst,name3) = 
let fun aux (xs,acc) =
 case all_except_option(name3,x::xs) of
     NONE   => aux(xs, acc)
   | SOME z => aux(xs, z@acc)
in
aux(lst,[""])
end
```

Both "get_substitutions" functions are supposed to do the same thing.
compare String1 to string list list, return single list made up of all lists containing String1 minus String1.

My attempts at using Tail Recursion have resulted in the following error.

```
Error: unbound variable or constructor: x

uncaught exception Error
  raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-
```

Here are a few examples of calling `get_substitutions2`:

```
get_substitutions2 ([["foo"],["there"]], "foo"); (* = [] *)
get_substitutions2 ([["fred","fredrick","freddie","F","freddy"],["Will","William","Willy","Bill"]],"Bill"); (* = ["Will","William","Willy"] *)
get_substitutions2 ([["a","b"],["a","c"],["x","y"]], "a"); (* = ["c","b"] *)
```

Comment: The error is coming up because (BIG SURPRISE!) `x` is unbound in your function. You don't define `x` anywhere, so the compiler doesn't know what it is. I think you just want `xs`, not `x::xs`. However, after spending about 10 minutes looking at your code, I can't figure out exactly what you're trying to do, and I don't think you have any idea what you're doing. For starters, your recursive helper function `acc` is missing a base case. You should also know if you should use `@` (concatenate) or `::` (prepend) based on the type of `z`, and what you want for your result.

Comment: Thank you for comment.  You are right, I have little idea of what I am doing because I am being given extreme basics and being asked to make intermediate code in a language I am unfamiliar with.  This would be why I asked for help.  I am having difficulty resolving how x::xs seems to be synonymous with hd xs, and also for combining lists as seen in function get_substitutions1.

Comment: I don't think the language is so much the problem as the [paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm). You don't seem very familiar with a lot of functional programming concepts (recursion, pattern matching, [cons-lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons#Lists), etc). You should try to ask more specific questions. You might have better luck chatting with the people in `#sml@irc.freenode.net`, since you can actually have a discussion there at a decent pace, unlike leaving comments on stackoverflow.

Comment: Pattern matching is exactly what I am attempting to figure out.  you mentioned the Base Case.  While this is simple with numbers as I was shown.  With strings the only way I know to start is with an empty string, and build onto it for the answer.  Which is what I was attempting to do.  Not everyone can take "hey 1+1=2" and from that spell Obfuscate.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: From the code you posted, I can't even tell that you're working with a string. But, again, posting comments here is really too slow to have a real discussion. You should go to the `sml` channel on freenode.net (`#sml@irc.freenode.net`). I'm in there right now, and there are lots of other people that probably actually use SML regularly there too (I prefer other functional languages like Clojure LISP and Scala to ML). If you don't have an IRC client, you can use their online interface: http://webchat.freenode.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same patterns you had for `get_substitutions1` in your `aux` function definition:

```
fun get_substitutions2 (lst,name3) = 
let fun aux ([],acc) = acc (* BASE CASE *)
      | aux (x::xs,acc) =  (* BINDING x IN PATTERN *)
 case all_except_option(name3,x) of
     NONE   => aux(xs, acc)
   | SOME z => aux(xs, z@acc)
in
aux(lst,[])
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is right. When we change to tail recursive call,  we also need to change the append order.  Should be `aux(xs, acc@z)` instead of `aux(xs, z@acc)`